# Bootstrap Columns colliding on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a `theme`, and I used a condition to create an additional `div` with the class of "row" after 3 posts/columns are created. It works as expected, except when I minimize the screen to `1024x768`, the columns have no margin in between them. And then they finally goes one under another one as expected on a smaller `viewport`. Not sure what to do, here's the code ...

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>

   <div class="container">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                <div class="row ">

        <?php 

        if (have_posts() ): 
        $counter = 0;
        while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        $counter++; ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_img_container">

            <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(450, 450), array('alt' => get_the_title(), 'class' => 'card_image img-responsive')  ); ?>


            <span class="card_readmore">View Post</span>
            </div>


            <div class="card_excerpt">
                <p class="content_category1"> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <span class="read_more">Read More</span> </a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


            <?php     if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
                  echo '</div><div class="row">';
                } ?> 


    <?php   
            endwhile;
                endif;
    ?> 
                </div> <!--Inner div ROW-->
            </div> <!--Main Div ROW-->
       </div> <!--Main Div ROW-->

  </div> <!--Container-->

  <?php // get_sidebar(); ?>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  content
</div>
```

Remember that the classes can be stacked on top of each other to get widht of 4 in MD-sized screen, and full width (12) in SM-Sized screen.

I hope I understand your problem.